# encountered the symbol FROM when expecting one of the following pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I am trying to extract year from `datefield` but when I use extract (year from 
datefield) I get this error

```
Encountered the symbol FROM when expecting one of the following pl sql

cursor o1 is 

select substr(tarifa,1,2), count(*)
from pol p, uvod u, doppov d
where extract(year FROM datum_dop) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate) 
and izdavanje >='1-jul-13'
and p.orgjed = u.sorgz (+)
and DATUM_PREKIDA is not null
and p.polica=d.polica and d.pov_dopl='P'
and d.status='F'
and cisti_ao(p.polica)!=0 
group by substr(tarifa,1,2);
```

Where did I made mistake ?

[image]

Comment: That's not the full error message? What was the list of tokens oracle was expecting?

Comment: I added the picture.

Comment: Sorry, but I couldnt copy-past error message because IDE doesnt let me do that. I try a couple of time to cpy error message but doesnt work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, this is Forms, probably 6i.

Its engine doesn't know `extract` function. Change that line to

```
where to_char(datum_dop, 'yyyy') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')
```

This would, though, make index on `datum_dop` column (if it exists) unusable and force Oracle to convert dates to strings, so you'd rather try with

```
where datum_dop >= trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy')
  and datum_dop < add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 12)
```

---

Other than that:

- `count(*)` should have an alias (if you plan to use it), e.g. `count(*) as broj_tarifa`
- if `izdavanje` is `date`, don't compare it to a string (`'1-jul-13'`) but date, e.g. `izdavanje >= to_date('01.07.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy')`
- use table aliases for **all** columns

Comment: I'd recommend you advocate use of `datum_dop BETWEEN datex and datey`, `datum_dop >= datex AND datum_dop < datey` or similar, rather than advocating conversion of thousands or millions of rows to char. Also, while youre recommending various improvements, ANSI92 style joins rather than ANSI89?

Comment: Certainly, @Caius. Thank you, I've edited the answer.